# Typescript parameter decorator for manipulating input

Tags: typescript, decorator, typescript-decorator

I want to write a decorator for the following use case:

```
function doSomethingWithADate(date: string | number | Date) {
    // do something with the passed in date
}
```

My problem is, that I don't know if the date is really of type string, number or date. I could do the necessary conversion inside the function but I don't think, that's the best way to do and I even if I re-use it using an additional function, there's still one additional line of code for every function of that kind.

What I want the decorator to do is:

1. Find every date-like argument
2. Convert it to a date if necessary
3. Use the manipulated arguments inside the function just like they were passed in that way.

Is that possible?